# Swipe tabs with Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I am using ActionBar with ViewPagerIndicator or ActionBarTabs. It's consume quite space. I have created a custom layout for  action bar,but it didnot work well for tabs.. I need some thing look like below image

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: but what is your problem?

Comment: @SimplePlan i  need more space? may i know why i get negative votes?

Comment: @AravindAsthme You should post some code (xml layout, Java). We can't help you with the information you have provided.

Comment: @enrmarc in xml i put three imageview in linear layout in java i have added getcustomview(R.layout.threeimageviewlayout);but i dont know how to add indicator over there..if its success i will add functionalities

Answer (score -1):

I guess there might me some logical errors in your code.There are two concept in what you are trying to do, first is you need to know how to work with Action bar(http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/) and second is working with Tab layout with swipeable views ([http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/).After](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/%29.After) learning the two concept try to sync it then you will get the desired result.

Comment: Don't paste any links answer your own . I have go through all links before I posted